# Difference between OPC UA 1.01, 1.02, and 1.03

Tags: opc-ua

I am trying to determine the main differences between the latest three revisions of the OPC UA specification. I'm working on testing out some OPC SDKs and have been asked to make sure they work with OPC UA 1.03. To do this, I need to know what the differences are between 1.01, 1.02, and 1.03.

I've read that 1.02 added HTTPS and 256 bit encryption support, and that 1.03 adds a Pub/Sub model, but I can't find a concise list of features.

I have tried looking through the documentation at [OPC Foundation](https://opcfoundation.org/developer-tools/specifications-unified-architecture), but it is quite verbose and doesn't nicely show what has been added each revision.

Can someone list the differences between the versions or point me to a resource that does?

Answer (score 1):

At least starting with 1.03, each of the specification part documents has a "highlights" table for that revision number.

Also, FWIW, Pub/Sub is coming in 1.04. It's not part of 1.03.

If there's a "release notes" style list somewhere for each version I'd love to know also...

That being said, you shouldn't need to know all the differences in order to make sure the SDK you're evaluating supports a certain version. Just ask the vendor/author what version it supports. They'll know.

Comment: Thanks. I did check out the "highlights" table previously, but it seemed to mostly contain info about the changes to the document itself, new best practice sections, etc. rather than OPC UA added features. If I come across a "release notes" list, I will update this ticket. I wanted to know the difference to make sure the vendor supports it, and whether they just say they support 1.03, or they actually have a certified SDK.